# How do I append to array as an extension in swift

Tags: swift

I wrote the following in swift and expected it to just work:

```swift
extension Array where Element : AnyCancellable
{
    mutating func add( event : NSNotification.Name, handler: @escaping () -> () )
    {
        let cancellation_token : AnyCancellable = event.sink( handler: handler)
        self.append(cancellation_token)        // error here
    }
}
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't - it says "**no exact matches in call to append**".
And if I comment out the append line, it compiles.
With this code however,

```swift
extension Array where Element : AnyCancellable
{
    mutating func add( event : NSNotification.Name, handler: @escaping () -> () )
    {
        let cancellation_token : Element = event.sink( handler: handler)   // error here
        self.append(cancellation_token)
    }
}
```

the assignment fails with a "**cannot convert value of type 'AnyCancellable' to specified type 'Element'**".

So it's like the where clause is doing nothing?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "And if I comment out the append line, it compiles" No it doesn't. "Value of type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'sink'." Clearly there is a lot more going on that you are not telling us. Tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the publisher from the `Notification.Name`, not the `Nofication.Name` itself (which doesn't have a `sink` method).

The main key is changing `Element : AnyCancellable` to `Element == AnyCancellable`. Also, the `handler` closure should take a `Notification` as a parameter.

```
extension Array where Element == AnyCancellable
{
    mutating func add( event : NSNotification.Name, handler: @escaping (Notification) -> () )
    {
        let cancellation_token = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: event)
            .sink(receiveValue: handler)
        self.append(cancellation_token)
    }
}
```

Comment: actually - I already had an extension method called "sink" on the NSNotification.Name, which does the publisher(for:).sink() stuff...   (I like extension methods :)).   -  but anyway - thanks for the solution!